# Deleted users in phpmyadmin on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp, root

Unluckily I have deleted almost all users in XAMPP MySQL database. I have a wordpress sites working there, but I can't access phpmyadmin to edit database or even make a copy of it.

This is the error code:

```
New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
```

I can't use MySQL to add new user...
How can I fix that? I only know that I have to add a new root account to access phpmyadmin from local network.
And for future - Do I need to remove some users when I transfer my website from XAMPP server to web server to make it safe? Or All the root users can't be reached from third person in the web?

Thanks for Your reply,
 Peter

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, after solving it for 4 hours I have made something better... I used Wordpress plugin "Duplicator" and just copied my website. Then I deleted XAMPP and installed it once more. I have imported my website and now it works fine - phpmyadmin too :)